# plotly sankey - is it able to put the node labels to the right for last layer(column)

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram

I have a  sankey chart created by python plotly with 8 layers(columns).

```py
dataset = pd.read_csv('cleanSankey.csv')

labelListTemp1 = list(set(dataset.source.values))
labelListTemp2 = list(set(dataset.target.values))
labelList = labelListTemp1 + labelListTemp2
sankey_node = list(dict.fromkeys(labelList))

def nodify(node_names):
    node_names = sankey_node
    # uniqe name endings
    ends = sorted(list(set([e[-1] for e in node_names])))
    
    # intervals
    steps = 1/len(ends)

    # x-values for each unique name ending
    # for input as node position
    nodes_x = {}
    xVal = 0
    for e in ends:
        nodes_x[str(e)] = xVal
        xVal += steps

    # x and y values in list form
    x_values = [nodes_x[n[-1]] for n in node_names]
    y_values = [0.1]*len(x_values)
    
    return x_values, y_values

nodified = nodify(node_names=sankey_node)
 
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey( node = dict( pad=15,thickness=15,line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),label = labelList,color = 'grey',x=nodified[0],y=nodified[1] ),
                                  link = dict(source = dataset.source.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
                                              target = dataset.target.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
                                              value = dataset.value),
                                              arrangement='snap')])


fig.update_layout(title="performance Goal user behavior monitor",margin=dict(l=150))
fig.write_html('perfUXRGoal.html', auto_open=True)
```

Issue:
The labels are  positioned to the right side of the nodes, but the the node labels for last layer, it's always positioned to the left side of the nodes.

Question:
Is it possible to put the labels to the right side of nodes for the last layer as well?

Screenshot sample:
[image]
Thanks,
Cherie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround.  Have an additional layer that has no label and all target nodes lead to it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

links = [
    {'source': 'start', 'target': 'A', 'value': 2},
    {'source': 'A', 'target': 'B', 'value': 1},
    {'source': 'A', 'target':'C', 'value':.5},
    {'source': 'B', 'target':'', 'value':10**-10},
    {'source': 'C', 'target':'', 'value':10**-10},



]

df = pd.DataFrame(links)
nodes = np.unique(df[["source","target"]], axis=None)
nodes = pd.Series(index=nodes, data=range(len(nodes)))

fig = go.Figure(
    go.Sankey(
        node={"label": nodes.index},
        link={
            "source": nodes.loc[df["source"]],
            "target": nodes.loc[df["target"]],
            "value": df["value"],
            "color": np.where(df["target"].eq(""), "white", "rgba(30,30,30,.3)")
        },
    )
)

fig
```

[image]