# Axis Labels outside of Plotly Sankey diagram, Python

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

This is my code:

```
def fig_sankey_creator(sankey_label, sankey_source, sankey_target, sankey_value, node_color, link_color):   




    fig_sankey = go.Figure(data = [go.Sankey(
                                node = dict(
                                label = sankey_label,
                                color = node_color,
                                pad = 10,
                            ),
                                link = dict(
                                        source = sankey_source,
                                        target = sankey_target,
                                        value = sankey_value,
                                        color = link_color,
                            ))])
    fig_sankey.update_layout(
            title_text = "Sankey diagram",
            height = 800,
            width = 1600,
            )
    fig_sankey.update_yaxes(ticklabelposition = "outside")
            
    return fig_sankey
```

and this is the outcome:
[image]

What I want to change is the axis labels not to be inside the plot but outside. How to achieve that? The `ticklabelposition` `outside` does not work. Thanks!

Comment: You meant the tick labels of yaxis?

Comment: Yes, the numbers (IDs) next to the nodes. I want them to be outside of the plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053171/16733101

Comment: It shows all the tick labels on the same (right side), I would prefer tick labels on the left side for the left nodes and vice versa for the right side. Just trying to avoid the tick labels to stay in the way of the Sankey links.

Comment: You may need to try a different library like [Holoviews](https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Sankey.html). Using `label_position='outer'` would work. Don't believe plotly sankey has this feature